# LIMIT, SINCE and UNTIL parameters in page feed

Tags: facebook-graph-api, limit, feed

I'm trying to get the news feed of page (I'm admin of that page) using the **limit**, **since** and **until** parameters, but it doesn't work, it doesn't work even in graph api explorer tool. I'm requesting the following:

`$fb->api("/PAGE_ID/feed?limit=100")`

but it always returns me the last 25 posts, the **since** and **until** parameters don't work also. What's the wrong in my code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the same problem, even in graph api explorer too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've found the right way to use these parameters. I should pass the limit or any other parameters as 3rd parameter when calling api method:

`$feed = $this->fb->api("/PAGE_ID/feed", "GET", array('limit' => 2));`

Comment: this is old, but wondering if you know the resulting URL for those of us not using the php sdk.

Answer (score 17):

For those not using the PHP SDK and are hitting the relevant Graph API URL directly, simply append

```
&limit=SOMEPOSITIVEINTEGER
```

to the end of the URL like so:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/PAGEGRAPHOBJECTID/posts/&since=2011-07-01&until=2012-08-08&access_token=ACCESSTOKEN&limit=100
```

Unfortunately, depending on which Graph resource you're hitting, you may get an error if the limit is over a certain threshold and there's no rhyme or reason to this that I can ascertain. For example, getting comments or likes for a post, I've used a limit of 4900 without getting an error. When getting posts from the page feed, that same number gave me an error and now I use a limit of 100 then paginate until my cron sees posts outside the date range.

I imagine though that FB would like for us to use the default limit of 25 and paginate so I'm personally refactoring to accomodate this.

Comment: Where are these params documented? I'm just getting started with the API and I've been looking at this page which doesn't mention them or even the access_token param. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/user/feed

Comment: Oh I see. It's "time-based pagination".

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with your code.  Near as I can tell, the Facebook Graph API is broken; the [documented](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) paging parameters have no effect when querying connections.

Comment: yes, paging parameters have no effects, but I've found how to make the limit and other parameters to work :) I'll write in my answer below.

Comment: unfortunately I can't answer to my own question for 8 hours... so I'll just post it as a comment

Answer (score 1):

For me, **`since`** and **`until`** work when used with the **`date_format=U`** parameter, providing values as UNIX timestamps:

`me/posts?fields=id,created_time&limit=100&date_format=U&since=1558355000&until=1558356000`

Tested in Graph API 2.12 and 3.3

Answer (score 1):

For me `since` and `until` are working when:

```
me/posts?limit=100&since=2017-01-23T13:11:12&until=2019-08-21T01:11:12&fields=id,created_time
```

or

```
me/posts?limit=100&since=2017-01-2313:11:12&until=2019-08-2101:11:12&fields=id,created_time
```